# Javascript focus event is not focusing first time its focus at the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am facing a problem in javascript event focus and blur I am trying to run a script in a if else condition on a input field text which has a date drop down coming from jQueryUi I am trying to apply a condition in which if the the user select the today date then I have to run the script otherwise don't run the script

https://camelia.ae/checkout/

Here is the link of the website try to add something in the cart

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      var deliveryDateInput = document.getElementById("delivery_date");

      deliveryDateInput.addEventListener("focus", function() {
        // Remove the previous blur event listener, if any
        this.removeEventListener("blur", handleDateBlur);
        
        // Attach the blur event listener
        this.addEventListener("blur", handleDateBlur);
      });

      function handleDateBlur() {
        var selectedDateParts = this.value.split("/");
        var selectedDate = new Date(selectedDateParts[2], selectedDateParts[1] - 1, selectedDateParts[0]);
        var today = new Date();
        today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

        if (selectedDate.getTime() === today.getTime()) {
          alert("Hello! You've selected today's date.");
        }
      }
    });
</script>
```

I have written this code in which I am trying to show the alert on the today date the problem I am facing is that this code is working but on the second time when I select first time it shows nothing but when I click second time its show alert.

Can anyone tell me the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
   let date = document.querySelector('#delivery_date');

   date.addEventListener('change', onDateChange)

   function getFormattedDate() {
        const today = new Date();
        const year = today.getFullYear();
        const month = (today.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0'); // Months are zero-based
        const day = today.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');

        return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
    }
    const formatedDate  = getFormattedDate()

    function onDateChange(e) {
        let selectedDate = e.target.value;
        if(selectedDate === formatedDate) {
            alert("Hello! You've selected today's date.");
        }
   }
</script>
```